# SASS @extend with wildcard

Tags: sass, css-selectors

I am having few classes as `txt-lg`, `txt-md`, `txt-sm`, `txt-tn` and I want to @extend it

```
.sp-slides{
  @extend .txt-*;
}
```

So `*` will replace to the all `lg`, `md`, `sm`, `tn` for `txt-` class.

Is it possible somehow using wild-card selector etc?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Extends do not work with wildcards or other forms of partial matching common in other languages.

Extend *can* match on individual simple selectors that compose another selector:

```
%foo.foo-bar {
    /* foo-bar */
}

%foo.foo-boo {
    /* foo-boo */
}

%foo.foo-buzz {
    /* foo-buzz */
}

.my-selector {
    @extend %foo;
}
```

Output:

```
.foo-bar.my-selector {
  /* foo-bar */
}

.foo-boo.my-selector {
  /* foo-boo */
}

.foo-buzz.my-selector {
  /* foo-buzz */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this I have already done.. but just wonder to know if it is possible to use wildcard selector. Hoping in future we could have it..